# Selenium IDE: base URL not saved

Tags: selenium

I've recently started to use Selenium IDE for the automatic testing of a website I'm working on. I've created all the test cases with the LIVE base URL. Then I created a test suite but now I would like to apply all the tests to the staging environment.

I tried two things:

1. Update the base URL from the test suite. I opened the test suite, when to each case and changed the base URL in the field at the top. Saved and closed.
2. Update the base URL in each test case, individually. Yep, I opened each test case (amd there are like 60 or something) and changed the base URL both in the top field and in the source (in the link rel tag). Saved and closed.

My problem is that none of these changes have been saved, I've applied them 3 days ago and now I've opened the test suite or the test cases, they still have the LIVE base URL.

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me figure out what I did wrong or if I'm obliged to start again from zero.

Best regards
Samkoukai

Answer (score 0):

Try opening each test case in an HTML editor (like Notepad++, or even just Windows Notepad) and edit this link to the base URL you want:

```
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply (I wonder how come I didn't think about it first, lol). I changed the base URL thanks to Sublime text and it got saved at last. 

Then when I opened the test suite in Selenium IDE, I just had to untick the option "remember base URL" because it kept remembering the live one.  I thus selected the right testing URL in the dropdown and set the option back to "remember base URL". It all seems to work the way I want now.